# ROR user authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my web app after a user logs in a new session is created so until he closes the browser he stays logged in. The problem appears when admin wants to ban the user who's browser is still open. Even though the user is banned and cannot log in anymore, he still stays logged in until he closes the browser or manually logs out. This definitely should be fixed.

Is it possible to add a verifying method to every action of every controller? Of course I mean a smart way - not copy/paste 100 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following to your application controller:

```
before_filter :sign_out_banned_user

def sign_out_banned_user
  if current_user.banned?
    session[:current_user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You are banned"
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: can you explain why to return false?

Comment: You may take a try of removing the `return false`. Without `return false`, after the `redirect_to` the code will continue and will go in the action. Then there will be duplicated `redirect_to` because you get into the action.

Answer (score 1):

You must reset the session also i think.

Comment: I have added back the line for reseting the session :)